# Изменение корневой папки Git

Tags: javascript, node.js, git

Есть такая структура папок
Projects:

```
│   .babelrc
│   .configs
│   .gitignore
│   server.js
│
└───src
    ├───Build
    │       bundle.js
    │
    ├───Scripts
    │       scripts.js
    │
    └───Styles
            style.css
```

Если инициализировать git в корневой папке (Projects) то в репозитрий зальется папка src, а она там не нужно нужно лишь толкьо ее содержимое.
Можно ли сделать так то бы git работал с папкой src в качестве корневой?
Решением было бы инициализировать git в самой папке src но я хочу разделить все конфигурационные файлы от кода. Возможно ли это реализовать?

Comment: В данном случае будет хорошо добавить в репозиторий всё это

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы считаете файл .gitignore "конфигурационным" - то нет, нельзя. Этот файл обязан находиться не выше корня репозитория - а вы не желаете смешивать его с кодом.

Точнее, есть один вариант, но я бы вам его не рекомендовал. Содержимое .gitignore можно перенести в файл .git/info/exclude - тогда он будет "отделен" от кода и вы сможете переносить корень репозитория туда, куда вам удобно. Но я не рекомендуя так делать - ведь файл .git/info/exclude не будет синхронизироваться между разными репозиториями, и его надо будет каждый раз настраивать заново.

---

Но в чем вообще проблема нахождения папки src в репозитории? Напротив, это получается довольно удобная структура. В дальнейшем вам может понадобиться хранить в репозитории документацию, тесты или скрипты системы непрерывной интеграции - и отдельная папка для кода будет кстати.

Comment: *.gitignore … обязан находиться в корне репозитория* — не совсем верно. его содержимое будет оказывать влияние на тот каталог, в котором он находится и на все вложенные каталоги. см. `man gitignore`.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin хм, и правда... Исправил.

Comment: Я бы с удовольствием оставил папку src но в репозитории который расположен на github другая архитектура папок...

Comment: @Павел тогда копируйте ее и не выдумывайте. Структура папок должна быть одинаковой для всех разработчиков, иначе могут быть проблемы. К примеру, со сборкой.